# Updating chart based on drop down selection

Tags: javascript

i'm making a chart about some data's. And i want to make the chart change based on a selected drop down option.

The value inside the drop down seems work. but the chart is not updating. any help?

```
<form>
        <select class="form-control btn-primary" id="sel1" onchange="options[selectedIndex].value&&self.location.reload(true)">
            <option value = "1">Layanan</option>
            <option value = "2">Hasil</option>
            <option value = "3">Waktu</option>
            <option value = "4">Biaya</option>
        </select>
    </form>
```

```
onunload = function(){
            var sel1 = document.getElementById('sel1');
            self.name = 'sel1idx' + sel1.selectedIndex;
        }

        onload = function(){
            var idx, sel1 = document.getElementById('sel1');
            sel1.selectedIndex = (idx = self.name.split('sel1idx')) ? idx[1] : 0;
        }

var temp = document.getElementById('sel1');

        if(temp == 1){
            var i = 0;
            var txt = "Layanan";
        }else if(temp == 2){
            var i = 1;
            var txt = "Hasil";
        }else if(temp == 3){
            var i = 2;
            var txt = "Waktu";
        }else if(temp == 4){
            var i = 3;
            var txt = "Biaya";
        }
```

i want to change the temp variable.

Answer (score 0):

If my understanding is correct, you are trying to store the value from the select dropdown? If so, you will need an event handler for when input is given, and then check to see if the input came from your select element; if so, you can go on to parse the value from the selected option.

But as I cannot see this "graph" you're talking about and it isn't completely clear what you're trying to accomplish, I am not completely sure what else to say.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like below.

```
<select class="form-control btn-primary" id="sel1" onchange="onChangeSelect()">
    <option value = "1">Layanan</option>
    <option value = "2">Hasil</option>
    <option value = "3">Waktu</option>
    <option value = "4">Biaya</option>
</select>
```

```
onunload = function(){
        var sel1 = document.getElementById('sel1');
        self.name = 'sel1idx' + sel1.selectedIndex;
    }



onload = function(){
        var idx, sel1 = document.getElementById('sel1');
        sel1.selectedIndex = (idx = self.name.split('sel1idx')) ? idx[1] : 0;
    }

var temp;

var onChangeSelect = function(){
   temp = $("#sel1").val();
};

    if(temp == 1){
        var i = 0;
        var txt = "Layanan";
    }else if(temp == 2){
        var i = 1;
        var txt = "Hasil";
    }else if(temp == 3){
        var i = 2;
        var txt = "Waktu";
    }else if(temp == 4){
        var i = 3;
        var txt = "Biaya";
    }
```

When the value selected in the select element changes the onChange will be triggered. So in the onChangeSelect(), the new value of temp will be read.